# jQuery won't execute with the animate: top 200px function. Yet it will with an animate: height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is some straight jQuery that hides the open div when clicked not shown, but still adds the height to the navigation to make it 
seem like it is dropping down.

This script works okay:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#openNav").click(function(){
            $("#nav").animate({height: "200px"});
        });
        $("#closeNav").click(function(){
            $("#nav").fadeOut();
            $("#nav").animate({height: "100px"});
        });
    });
</script>
```

This doesn't animate at all when clicked:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#openNav").click(function(){
        $("#nav").animate({top: "+100px"});
    });
    $("#closeNav").click(function(){
        $("#nav").fadeOut();
        $("#nav").animate({height: "-100px"});
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need the DOM to have `position:relative` or `absolute` in order for positional properties like `left`, `top`, etc. to take effect in css.

Answer (score 0):

`#nav` should have `position: relative` or `position: absolute` for `top` animation